# Anti Dumping Techniques (C++)

Tags: memory, x64dbg, dumping, memory-dump, dump

how would I go about blocking Memory Dumps by corrupting the PE Header or blocking the Debugger to get an Handle?

I tried [this](https://github.com/LordNoteworthy/al-khaser/tree/master/al-khaser/AntiDump) already but it didnt work. Scylla could still dump it fine.

Comment: You can't block memory dumps as you don't control the machine the code is run on, your best bet is to look at encryption.